# Azure Devops Powershell failing to run dotnet tools locally

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

My setup:

Azure Devops Server 2019 Express
Self-Hosted agent
running through localhost

.net 6.x installed

Problem:

I have a pipeline that runs a PowerShell task attempting to execute SqlPackage `SqlPackage : The term 'SqlPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`

To keep it simple, I have created an Inline script:

```
Write-Host "Testing"
SqlPackage
```

You can see the output below, the script shows "Testing" but then fails trying to run SqlPackage

[image]
[image]

To confirm, if I just run SqlPackage in my local powershell command line, I get
`SqlPackage: Command-line tool for creating and deploying SQL Server databases and DACPAC packages. (162.0.52.1) Copyright (c) 2023 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

Comment: You have an issue with the Execution Policy.  Read the link at top of your picture above to solve issue.

Comment: If I run C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\test.ps1'" it works as expected.

I have also run  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

No change.

Comment: Your picture doesn't show entire command.  What is the difference in working and non working?  It looks like the execution policy is causing the issue and you need to change the policy.  Read the link in your picture.

Comment: The piped command is -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted? As above, I copied the exact command output by the task and ran it locally, works fine.